# Produto vetorial em C com entrada de arquivos .dat

Tags: c, array

Seja o código abaixo, onde o arquivo de entrada vetores.dat, em cada linha, tem 6 números onde os 3 primeiros são componentes de um vetor "u" e os 3 últimos são componentes de um vetor "v".O arquivo de saída vetorial.dat deve ter 3 componentes em cada linha do produto vetorial de u por v.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6
int main(){

FILE *entrada = NULL;
FILE *saida = NULL;
int i=0;
double componente;
double p[N];
double vetorial_x, vetorial_y, vetorial_z;

entrada = fopen("vetores.dat","r");
if(entrada == NULL) printf("O arquivo vetores.dat não existe\n");

saida = fopen("vetorial.dat","w");

while(fscanf(entrada,"%lf",&componente) != EOF){ 
    if(i < N){ 
        p[i] = componente;
        i++;
    }

    else if(i = N){ 
        vetorial_x = p[1]*p[5] - p[2]*p[4];
        vetorial_y = p[2]*p[3] - p[0]*p[5];
        vetorial_z = p[0]*p[4] - p[1]*p[3];
        fprintf(saida,"%.3lf\t%.3lf\t%.3lf",vetorial_x,vetorial_y,vetorial_z);
        i=1;
        p[0] = componente;
        }
    }
return 0;

}
```

O programa adiciona os 6 números encontrados em cada linha de "vetor.dat" em um array p[6] logo após ele realiza o produto vetorial.

O problema é que ao colocar um arquivo "vetor.dat" com 45 linhas o programa imprime um arquivo "vetorial.dat" com apenas 38 linhas (deveria imprimir 45). Ao colocar um arquivo "vetor.dat" com 4 linhas o programa gera um arquivo "vetorial.dat" com 3 linhas.

O código parece sempre gerar um arquivo com menos vetores de saída que vetores de entrada.

Não sei se o erro está na passagem

```
  while(fscanf(entrada,"%lf",&componente) != EOF){
```

por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Só encontrei esse erro:

```
 else if(i = N)
```

Onde certamente deveria ser:

```
else if(i == N)
```